# Oh Trogdor, could you burninate [card]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I don't think this one adds *much* and should probably be verboten to avoid future use.

If you'd prefer to retag the 61 questions, then I have a few suggestions:

- [credit](/questions/tagged/credit) + [card](/questions/tagged/card) => [credit-card](/questions/tagged/credit-card) ( **18** / 61 )
- [smart](/questions/tagged/smart) + [card](/questions/tagged/card) => [smartcard](/questions/tagged/smartcard) ( **8** / 61 )
- [card](/questions/tagged/card) + [reader](/questions/tagged/reader) => [cardreader](/questions/tagged/cardreader) (**5** / 61 )  This would be a **new tag**

and I've already retagged a few by hand -- so it's more like 50 now.

Comment: Does anyone else think that `[smart-card]` and `[card-reader]` would be better tags?  Or are "smartcard" and "cardreader" commonly written each as one word?

Comment: @Bill, I just went with [smartcard] because *it exists*.  If you'd prefer to use the hyphen, feel free!  And as to your question, I've seen creditcard as one word much more often than I've seen the other two as one word.  We could ask on the English Language site, but I suspect this is just technology working its way into the vernacular.

Comment: Not that I'd trust Wikipedia as a definitive source, but [Credit Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card), [Smart Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card), and [Card Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_reader) are all listed as *two* word phrases.

Comment: I moved the remaining ~50 over to more relevant tags, including the tag [playing-cards].  There are currently no questions marked [card].

Comment: Can we burninate the burninate tags and meme?

Comment: @tvanfosson I see a [new rabble-rousing question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) there!

Comment: Definitely two words, not one. I don't understand the contempt for hyphens in tags that we have around here.

Comment: "131 questions" for [card], with questions using card for many different meanings, is it burninated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]